# How to find unique elements from list of list of string based on some elements using scala?

Tags: scala, list, scala-collections

I want to filter the list of list based on few elements in it.

```
 pritnln("databind = "datamap)

 dataBind = List((List(3,60,90,T3,T6),List(3,90,89,T32,T5),List(3,60,90,T5,T6), List(3,120,89,T32,T5))
```

I want to filter this list[list[string]] based on unique first elements present in each list. If the first three elements are repeating, I don't want to get it.

My expected output

`List((List(3,60,90,T3,T6),List(3,90,89,T32,T5),List(3,120,89,T32,T5))`

When I checked in some question they have used for list of tuple

```
databind.groupBy(v => (v._1, v._2, v._3)).keys.ToList
```

How can I do this for the above mentioned list ?

Comment: List((List(3,60,90,T3,T6),List(3,90,89,T32,T5),List(3,60,90,T5,T6), List(3,120,89,T32,T5)) is not a List[List[String]]

Comment: @TerryDactyl it's probably the output of println(dataBind), so "3", "60", etc.

Comment: yes its the output of println(databind) . . databind I have created by using zip command in different lists.

Comment: There is also an unmatched `(`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lists always contain more than 3 elements:

```
scala> val l = List(List(1,2,3,4), List(2,3,4,5), List(1,2,3,5))
l: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(2, 3, 4, 5), List(1, 2, 3, 5))

scala> l.groupBy(_.take(3))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[List[Int],List[List[Int]]] = Map(List(1, 2, 3) -> List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 5)), List(2, 3, 4) -> List(List(2, 3, 4, 5)))
```

It is then up to you what you do with the groups. For example if you only want the Lists with a unique first 3 elements then:

```
scala> res1.collect{ case (_, List(l)) => l}
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to group lists based on first few elements of every item, you can go about doing the following:

```
scala> val dataBind = List(List(3,60,90,"T3","T6"),List(3,90,89,"T32","T5"),List(3,60,90,"T5","T6"), List(3,120,89,"T32","T5"))
dataBind: List[List[Any]] = List(List(3, 60, 90, T3, T6), List(3, 90, 89, T32, T5), List(3, 60, 90, T5, T6), List(3, 120, 89, T32, T5))
scala> dataBind.groupBy(_.take(3)).mapValues(_.head).values.toList
res8: List[List[Any]] = List(List(3, 120, 89, T32, T5), List(3, 60, 90, T3, T6), List(3, 90, 89, T32, T5))
```

You can specify the transformation of your choice inside ***mapValues*** method to derive the desired result.